# Get items from list where inner list contains set of enum-values

Tags: c#, linq, enums, .net-3.5

I have a class containing a list of enum-values:

```
class MyClass
{
    List<Category> ListProperty = ...
}
```

Now I have a list containing elements of `MyClass` which I want to filter based on their enum-values-list.

`Category` is marked with `Flags` to enable binary combination:

```
enum Category
{
    None = 0x00,
    Basic = 0x1,
    Geometry = 0x2,
    // ...
    Base_Geometry = 0x100
}
```

The list within `MyClass` may consist of an arbitrary number of enum-values that might or might not be binarily combined:

```
var m = new Myclass { 
    ListProperty = new List<Category> { 
        Category.Some_Category | Category.Another_Category, 
        Category.Basic
    }
});
myList.Add(m);
```

Now to retrieve all elements within `myList` that contain a given `Category` I use this:

```
var cat = Category.Geometry;
var result = myList.Where(x => x.ListProperty.Any(y => (y & cat) == cat));
```

The problem now arises when `cat` consist of multiple enum-values. E.g. when `cat` is equal to `Category.Geometry | Category.Base_Geometry` I want to select all elements that have either `Geometry`, `Base_Geometry` or even both in their `ListProperty`. In this case `result` is empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This condition

```
var result = myList.Where(x => x.ListProperty.Any(y => (y & cat) == cat));
```

requires that `y` contained all flags inside the `cat`. If you need `y` to contain any of the flags within `cat`, compare the result of `&` to zero:

```
var result = myList.Where(x => x.ListProperty.Any(y => (y & cat) != 0));
```

**Note:** Consider marking your `Category` enum with `[Flags]` attribute, and using [`Enum.HasFlag`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.hasflag%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) method to check an overlap ([Q&A with the explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8447/335858)):

```
// Requires .NET 4 or later
var result = myList.Where(x => x.ListProperty.Any(y => y.HasFlag(cat));
```

Comment: I marked my enum with `Flags` actually. However `HasFlags` is only defined on .NET4, which I can´t use.

Comment: @HimBromBeere I see - I didn't realize that you are on an earlier version of .NET.

Comment: I added the appropriate tag to the question.